# Apple pay fraud detection for pending payments with Stripe

Tags: ios, stripe-payments, applepay, fraud-prevention

Hi we are using Apple pay with PKPaymentSummaryItemTypePending.

We have users who are using apple pay with stolen credit cards, so they're blocked by stripe but ApplePay allows it.

We normally charge credit cards with [captured=false](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_charge) to verify credit cards

If we do that with apple pay, it will consume the token.

So as a work around, we will request user to approve two apple pay requests, one will be charged with captured=false, then the other for payment.

Is there a way to verify apple pay token without consuming the token?

Answer (score 0):

from Stripe:

> You may attach an apple pay token to a customer.
>   Stripe will automatically attempt a $0 / $1 authorization once you
>   attach a token to a customer. The authorization will happen once a
>   customer's created, or if they're using Checkout. Here's a link with a
>   little more information:
>
> https://support.stripe.com/questions/why-does-my-customer-see-an-extra-1-00-charge-on-their-statement
>
> That authorization doesn't use the token, it's a back end event that
>   happens on our side. You can definitely perform to charge the token
>   separate of the authorization.